# What are the effects if i run this script?

Tags: script, autohotkey, alt

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#=::Return
; Disable Alt+F4
!F4::Return
```

Comment: The line `; Disable Alt+F4` might possibly be giving a hint as to what effect the script might have.

Comment: Thanks. But besides the obvious, what other problems may arise after running the script? In my case, "Alt" key somehow disables my entire keyboard. Pressing it once will enable it back.

Comment: Without trying it (I have no reason to) then I would assume that it disables Alt-F4. If you are having trouble with it not working as expected then you should tell people what you are expecting to happen and what is *actually* happening. Perhaps even mention where you got this script. You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1303024/edit) your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing this script does is disable shortcut keys for `Alt+F4` and `WindowsKey+Equals`